# A subsets property for finite cyclic groups

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, additive-combinatorics

Consider the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_n=\{0,1,\cdots,n-1\}$ (of order $n$).
It is our conjecture that:

If $n\geq 8$ then there exist subsets $B,C$ such that $|B|\neq |C|$
and 
$$
\{0,1,n-1\}\cap (B-B)=\{0,1,n-1\}\cap (C-C)=\{0\},
$$
$$ 
\{0,1,n-1\}+B=\{0,1,n-1\}+C=\mathbb{Z}_n
$$
(especially if $n$ is even).

Note that the property is not valid if $n<8$ and
$A-A=\{a_1-a_2: a_1,a_2\in A\}$.

Comment: Are you sure it is invalid for all $n<8$? For $n=6$, I think that $B=\{0,3\}$ and $C=\{0,2,4\}$ do the job.

Comment: However, for $n=7$, there is no solution, since the conditions force $n/3\le|B|,|C|\le n/2$, and so we always have $|B|=|C|=3$.

Comment: @ jpvee. You are right, it is true for $n<6$ and $n=7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending the example for $n=6$, made in my comment, it is easy to find a general solution for $n\ge8$:

Take $C=\left\{0,2,4,6,\ldots,2\cdot(\lfloor n/2\rfloor - 1)\right\}$ and $B=(C\setminus\{2,4\})\cup\{3\}$. It is easy to verify that these sets satisfy all of your conditions.